# Xamarin.Forms - Variable on multiple pages

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms application with BLE implentation.
In the app I want to create an app with a flyout structure.
For this, however, some of the variables/data are needed in several pages of the app.
The data is only needed for the C# implementation and not for the XAML implementation.
Within the class/page, the transfer of variables and data works great. However, not when accessing another page.

I have already tried global functions, getter & setter as well as delegates, but have not found out a solution to the problem.

Do any of you have an idea about this or even a solution?
Thanks

Delegates
global functions (not private)
getter & setter functions

Comment: Without getting into the details of why globals may not be a good long term solution, why do you say that global getters and setters are not a solution to your problem?

Comment: **Add to question enough code to see what you are trying to do**. I understand the code won't work, may not even compile, but that is the starting point. Most importantly, show **what** on a page you are trying to control.

Comment: you need provide concrete detail if you want a useful answer.  This is very vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are THREE "static" techniques that are good to know about.

---

**1. XAML `x:Static`**

```xml
...
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace"
...

<Label Text="{x:Static local:MyClass.MyGlobalValue}" />
```

```cs
public class MyClass
{
  public static string MyGlobalValue;
}
```

---

**2. XAML `StaticResource`**

```xml
<Label BackgroundColor="{StaticResource MyDarkColor}" />
```

In App.xaml:

```xml
<Application ...
  <Application.Resources>
    <Color x:Key="MyDarkColor">#112233</Color>
...
```

---

**3. Instance property "proxy" of a static value.**

This "trick" accesses a "static" via an "instance property". Thus, it looks like any other property, to other code (and XAML).

```xml
<Label BackgroundColor="{Binding MyDarkColor}" />
```

```cs
// In the class that `BindingContext` is set to:
public static Color MyGlobalValue;

public Color MyDarkColor => MyGlobalValue;
```

IF the static is in a different class:

```cs
// In the class that `BindingContext` is set to:
public SomeType MyDarkColor => Class1.MyGlobalValue;

...
public class Class1
{
  public static SomeType MyGlobalValue;
}
```